# How to get direct link of the file from Dropbox Chooser

Tags: dropbox

In [the document of Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) we can get a share page url from `files[0].link`, but we need direct download link. How do I get it?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in [the forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=93129#post-511071).

Added `data-link-type="direct"` attribute for the Dropbox chooser button.

```
<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" data-link-type="direct" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Comment: Mitch, yes, I hope that the information is going to be written in the document in the near future.

Comment: this is documented officially now too, under "Chooser button": https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser

Comment: It seems from here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en that you can get a direct link from the preview link simply by replacing www with dl with the added advantage (it seems) that the link won't expire after 4 hours.

Comment: @GaryBishop Great suggestion. Its now 3 months later. Does this `www->dl` hack still work for you or has Dropbox "fixed" it somehow?

Comment: It is still in their public doc, so I assume it is expected behavior. I'm not using it that way right now so I haven't tried recently.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the way to do this now (Sept 2014), is to use the preview link, which doesn't expire, but change the `dl=0` flag to `dl=1`.